# How to make a point light shine through a material

Tags: materials, transparency, lighting

I Want to make this lamp with a point light inside it and have it shine through the appropriate faces.
So far I've put the point light inside and made the faces transparent via the shading nodes in the pic below however the light isn't shining through anyone know how I can achieve this?

---

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: What renderer?  Cycles or Eevee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transmission and Translucent materials are usually used for this type of behavior

Transmission - Glass

Translucent - leafs and paper-like materials

[image]

If the light source is important for rest scene lightning, it is usually a good idea (for performance reasons) to remove this material for all light rays except camera one:

[image]